# import data in r with more precision

Tags: r, readr

I want to import a data which is in CSV format into r-studio

The data is in this manner

```
1732.7193603515625 ,7825.7729492187500 
1732.7191162109375 ,7825.7714843750000 
1732.7191162109375 ,7825.7714843750000 
1732.7191162109375 ,7825.7714843750000 
1732.7189941406250 ,7825.7709960937500 
1732.7189941406250 ,7825.7709960937500 
1732.7189941406250 ,7825.7709960937500 
1732.7193603515625 ,7825.7709960937500
```

but when I import using this code

```
library(readr)
GPSDATA_Copy1 <- read_csv("D:/Desktop/GPSDATA - Copy1.TXT", 
    col_types = cols(`lat` = col_double(), 
        `lon` = col_double()))
View(GPSDATA_Copy1)
```

but it is importing in this format with less precision

1732.719,7825.772 
1732.719,7825.771 
1732.719,7825.771 
1732.719,7825.771 
1732.718,7825.770 
1732.718,7825.770 
1732.718,7825.770 
1732.719,7825.770

how to solve this problem

Comment: The viewer in RStudio will only show a few digits, but they are all imported. Take a look at `format(GPSDATA_Copy1[1, ], nsmall = 10)`.

Answer (score 3):

The viewer in RStudio only shows a few digits. They are however all imported correctly, which you can test by using `format`, as the following example demonstrates.

```
library(readr)

tmp <- tempfile()
cat("1732.7193603515625 ,7825.7729492187500 
    1732.7191162109375 ,7825.7714843750000 
    1732.7191162109375 ,7825.7714843750000 
    1732.7191162109375 ,7825.7714843750000 
    1732.7189941406250 ,7825.7709960937500 
    1732.7189941406250 ,7825.7709960937500 
    1732.7189941406250 ,7825.7709960937500 
    1732.7193603515625 ,7825.7709960937500", 
    file = tmp)

test <- read_csv(tmp, col_names = c("A", "B"))
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   A = col_double(),
#>   B = col_double()
#> )

format(test[[1, ]], nsmall = 10)
#> [1] "1732.7193603516" "1732.7191162109" "1732.7191162109" "1732.7191162109"
#> [5] "1732.7189941406" "1732.7189941406" "1732.7189941406" "1732.7193603516"
```

Comment: but the above code you have given stores in string format i need it in float format

Comment: @anveshtadii no. take a look at `typeof(test$A)`. The data is stored as double (=float) with all the information. I tried to show that fact by displaying more digits, which can be best achieved by formatting as character. But this doesn't change that your data is stored as double when read with `read_csv()`.